# Python: select by index, print column item

Tags: python, indexing

It's getting very close to doing what I want, which is getting the user to select an item in a list by it's index number (0-11).

When I enter a number i.e. 5, it prints "`You selected [5] as origin point"`..great! but I'd like it to show the name of the plot, not the index number. The name is in column 2(if the index column is counted as 0). I realise it's asking for integer but I'm hoping it's easy fixed.

Other problem is if I enter 18, it print `"You selected [18]..."`, but there is no 18.

```
def fmp_sel():
    DataPlotLoc= file('MonPlotDb.csv', 'rU')
    fmpList = csv.reader(DataPlotLoc, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    next(fmpList, None)
    for item in enumerate(fmpList):
        print "[%d] %s" % (item)

    while True:
        try:
            in_Sel = raw_input(('''Choose a plot from list, or 'q' to quit: '''))

            if in_Sel == 'q':
                print 'Quit?'
                conf = raw_input('Really? (y or n)...')
                if conf == 'y':
                    print 'Seeya!'
                    break
                else:
                    continue

            in_Sel = DataPlotLoc[int(in_Sel) + 1] # The +1 is to align to correct index
            print 'You selected', in_Sel, 'as origin point'
            break

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print 'Error: Try again'
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking! Consider to rewrite the question to get more answers and describe in more detail what you already have: What is DataPlotLoc?

Comment: Where are you calling `fmp_sel()`? Also, you may want `yield` instead of `next`, and, perhaps most closest to the problem you have: you're indexing `DataPlotLoc` which is a file object, not `fmpList` or the result of `fmp_sel` in case it's a generator.

Comment: `DataPlotLoc` is a `file` object, you can't index it with `[int(in_Sel) + 1]`. `fmpList` is a `csv.reader` object, not a list. To read all the rows of the `'MonPlotDb.csv'` file into memory where they _can_ be indexed, try `fmpList = [row for row in DataPlotLoc]` after the `next(fmpList, None)` line.

Comment: `DataPlotLoc= file('MonPlotDb.csv', 'rU')` : Here, `DataPlotLoc` is a file. And here `DataPlotLoc[int(in_Sel) + 1]`, you're using at as a iterable ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to fmpList to a list, csv reader will loop trough only once,

and also you can change the code as

```
DataPlotLoc= file('MonPlotDb.csv', 'rU')
fmpList = list(csv.reader(DataPlotLoc, dialect=csv.excel_tab))
for item in enumerate(fmpList):
   print "[%d] %s" % (item)
if fmpList:
   while True:
         try:
            in_Sel = raw_input(('''Choose a plot from list, or 'q' to quit: '''))
            in_Sel = DataPlotLoc[int(in_Sel)][1] # The +1 is to align to correct index
            print 'You selected', in_Sel, 'as origin point'
            break    
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print 'Error: Try again'
```